# ¿Cómo llenar el área a la izquierda de la curva con cmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colab

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el cual se tienen datos de coordenadas **X, Y** que forman una curva de tipo sinusoidal creciente en forma vertical.

Quiero realizar plots con `colormap` de modo que mientras mas se aleja la coordenada **X** del origen (-5,0) el colormap se torne rojo como se muestra en la gráfica, quiero que el relleno de colormap se aplique desde el limite izquierdo de **X**, en este caso -5, hasta la curva que lo delimita.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

#Generar Datos
y=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
x=np.sin(y)*y+2

#Generar Array
xx=np.asarray(x)
yy=np.asarray(y)

path = Path(np.array([xx,yy]).transpose())
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')
plt.gca().add_patch(patch)

im = plt.imshow(xx.reshape(yy.size,1),  cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,interpolation="nearest",
                origin='left',extent=[-5,10,0,10],aspect="auto", clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)
im.set_clip_path(patch)
```

[image: Gráfica 1]